# Cauchy Riemann question help?

Tags: complex-analysis

Find if the function is analytical  $w=\frac1{z^2}$  I dont know how to separate $u$ and $v$ here...I mean I have
$$w = \frac1{x^2 + 2ixy - y^2}.$$what is $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ here?

Comment: Separate the denominator into its real and imaginary parts, then multiply by the conjugate over itself. From here, it's just some algebra.

Comment: How would you express $\frac{1}{3-2i}$ as $a + ib$?

The same applies here.

Comment: Yep, if you want $u$ and $v$, you should rationalize the denominator. If you want, you could also use the fact that the composition of analytic functions is analytic. That depends on what the problem is asking and what they have given you already. $z^2$ is analytic and $\frac{1}{z}$ is analytic everywhere except the origin, so $\frac{1}{z^2}$ is analytic everywhere except the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\text{Re}(1/z^2)$ as  $$\frac{1}{2z^2} + \frac{1}{2\bar{z}^2} = \frac{z^2 + \bar{z}^2}{2|z|^4} = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$$
and similarly for the imaginary part. This will give you your $u$ and $v$.